# The google maps isLocationOnEdge() method is not working for data layer features

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the lines geometries passing from the clicked point. When I call `google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge`  by adding the data 
    directly on map for those features I am getting a successful result.

You can see the sample code from this [JSFiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/poojamadiwal/1sqa5ouh/1/)

**code snippet (from fiddle1):**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>GOOGLE Map</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="google.jpg" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map">
  </div>
  <script>
    var map;
    var TILE_SIZE = 256;

    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lng: 73.76606472,
          lat: 46.7578125
        },
        zoom: 21
      });
      //  map.data.loadGeoJson(href = "groupgeo.json");
      // map.data.addListener('click', identifyFeatures );
      map.addListener('click', identifyFeatures);
      var cord = [{
          lat: 44.7578125,
          lng: 72.76606472
        },
        {
          lat: 46.7578125,
          lng: 73.76606472
        }
      ];
      var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: cord,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });
      flightPath.setMap(map);

      function identifyFeatures(evt) {
        var featuresHits = [];
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(evt.latLng, flightPath, 0.123444)) {
          featuresHits.push(flightPath);

        }
        alert("Total Features: " + featuresHits.length);
      };
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDxBykE_KdCA6Etkewrera3hO3qep0IOxM&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

But when I call `google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge` by adding the 
features on the map via a data layer I am getting this method's result is always 
false (its not even depending on whatever tolerance I had set)

You can see the sample code from this [JSFiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/poojamadiwal/e0x8wr5u/3/).

**code snippet (from fiddle2)**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>GOOGLE Map</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="google.jpg" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map">
  </div>
  <script>
    var map;
    var TILE_SIZE = 256;

    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lng: 73.76606472,
          lat: 46.7578125
        },
        zoom: 21
      });

      var geoJSON = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "red_line.963",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [72.76606472, 44.7578125],
            [73.76606472, 46.7578125]
          ]
        },
        "geometry_name": "geometry",
        "properties": {
          "text_value": null,
          "redline_id": 146
        }
      };
      map.data.addGeoJson(geoJSON); //adding data layer
      map.addListener('click', identifyFeatures);


      function identifyFeatures(evt) {
        var featuresHits = [];
        map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
          var type = feature.getGeometry().getType();
          if ("LineString" == type) {
            var polygonCords = [];
            var pointOnLine = null;
            feature.getGeometry().forEachLatLng(function(latlng) {
              polygonCords.push(latlng);
            });
            var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
              paths: polygonCords,
            });
            if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(evt.latLng, polyline, 0.123444)) {
              featuresHits.push(feature);
            }
          }
        });
        alert("Total Features: " + featuresHits.length);
      };
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDxBykE_KdCA6Etkewrera3hO3qep0IOxM&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the creation of your [google.maps.Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#Polyline), that doesn't have a `paths` property, it should be `path` (the [google.maps.Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#Polygon) has a `paths` property):

```
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
       paths: polygonCords,
});
```

should be:

```
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: polygonCords,
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9h2o84sd/)

**code snippet:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>GOOGLE Map</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="google.jpg" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map">
  </div>
  <script>
    var map;
    var TILE_SIZE = 256;

    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lng: 73.76606472,
          lat: 46.7578125
        },
        zoom: 21
      });

      var geoJSON = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "red_line.963",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [72.76606472, 44.7578125],
            [73.76606472, 46.7578125]
          ]
        },
        "geometry_name": "geometry",
        "properties": {
          "text_value": null,
          "redline_id": 146
        }
      };
      map.data.addGeoJson(geoJSON); //adding data layer
      map.addListener('click', identifyFeatures);


      function identifyFeatures(evt) {
        var featuresHits = [];
        map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
          var type = feature.getGeometry().getType();
          if ("LineString" == type) {
            var polygonCords = [];
            var pointOnLine = null;
            feature.getGeometry().forEachLatLng(function(latlng) {
              polygonCords.push(latlng);
            });
            var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: polygonCords,
            });
            if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(evt.latLng, polyline, 0.123444)) {
              featuresHits.push(feature);
            }
          }
        });
        alert("Total Features: " + featuresHits.length);
      };
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDxBykE_KdCA6Etkewrera3hO3qep0IOxM&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```